# Filter a ICollectionView to order strings based off of how early a searched for term exists

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, collectionview

I'm looking to arrange a ICollectionView called `FilteredStrings` of string objects based off of how early the searched string appears in each string. My ICollection is being instantiated with `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_repository.GetObjects());`.

The `GetObjects()` just returns a `IEnumerable<string>()` that were collected in the repository.

My original list looks like so:

```
ObjAect
ObjectA
AObject
ObjectB
ObjectC
```

The user would type in the searchbox in the UI, so in this case, they would search `A` and then the ICollectionView should filter to only show the strings that contain the search textm but then also reorder them based off of how early the searched test appears.

Results should be this:

```
AObject
ObjAect
ObjectA
```

My current code looks like this:

```
public void Search(string searchText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
    {
        FilteredComponentViewModels.Filter = null;
        return;
    }
    FilteredComponentViewModels.Filter = s => s.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing `ICollectionView` immediately in your view class, or are you extending from one of the provided discrete implementations (`CollectionView` base class, or its children `BindingListCollectionView`, `ListCollectionView`, and `ItemCollection`)?

Comment: Apologies for that mate, it's a `CollectionViewSource`. I've updated the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ICollectionView` implementations which support sorting (identifiable by the `CanSort` property), we can assign an implementation of `IComparer` to the `ICollectionView.CustomSort` property.

Since our underlying collection is simply `IEnumerbale<string>`, we can use an existing implementation of `System.StringComparer` from the `System.Runtime.Extensions.dll` assembly:

```
FilteredComponentViewModels = GetDefaultView(_repository.GetObjects())
                              as ListCollectionView;
FilteredComponentViewModels.CustomSort = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
```

Comment: out of interest then, would this hide the values that don't contain then searched text and then reorder the list to: order of which the string contains the searched text first. Like the example in my post?

Comment: No, you would add `FilteredComponentViewModels.CustomSort = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` to the end of your `Search` method. You'll still need to set `Filter`. Incidentally, I'd also recommend changing your filter to use `Contains` instead of `IndexOf` just for simplicity/clarity.

Comment: Also take note of `as ListView` - this implementation of `ICollectionView` is one that supports sorting (its `CanSort` property returns true).

Comment: Superstar, that worked perfectly. Thank you for educating me on this :)